# Updating Multiple records in a singular update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been at this the past few hours and I finally though I would ask for help. I'm trying to update multiple distinct records in one table with multiple records in another table. Heres the set up:

Table x (QuestID, SectionID, Questxt) PK= QuestID

Table y (QuestAGID, QuestID, AGID) PK = QuestAGID

For some context, one table has questions and another has question answers. Questions match up to a section. Each question answer matches up to one question. With duplicating the records in the question answer table I now have 2 of the same records in the question answer table for one question. I want to be able to take those duplicate records and replace the question identifier with the new questions I have created. I am having trouble coming up with an update statement that would be able to replace the values one for one on multiple records.

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
declare @a as int
select @a = Count(x.sectionid) from x
where Sectionid=6584

update y
set QuestId = (select QuestId, ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (ORDER BY questid) AS Row2
    from x 
    where SectionId=7700)
from y
join x on y.QuestId=x.QuestId
where x.Questid IN 
( 
select top (@a) y.QuestId, ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (ORDER BY y.Questid) as Row1
    from y
inner join x
on y.QuestId=x.QuestId
where x.SectionId=6584
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is a sample of results from the two sub queries:

Query 1

```
select QuestionId, ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (ORDER BY questionid)
    from Questions 
    where SectionId=7700
```

Results:

```
QuestionId     column2    
-------------  ---------- 
31254          1          
31255          2
```

Query 2

```
declare @a as int
select @a = Count(Questions.sectionid) from Questions
where Sectionid=6584

select top (@a) Questions_AnswerGroup.Questionid, ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (ORDER BY Questions_AnswerGroup.Questionid) 
from Questions_AnswerGroup
inner join Questions
on Questions_AnswerGroup.QuestionId=Questions.QuestionId
where Questions.SectionId=6584
```

Result:

```
Questionid     column2    
-------------  ---------- 
24990          1          
24991          2
```

2ND EDIT: I will clarify this as much as possible to help everyone uneerstand and thanks already everyone for taking a look.

So here was my first step, I duplicated the Question_AnswerGroup records based on the section number.

```
insert into Questions_AnswerGroup (Questions.QuestionId,
Questions_AnswerGroup.AnswerGroupId,Questions_AnswerGroup.ControlTypeId,
         Questions_AnswerGroup.IsRequired,Questions_AnswerGroup.Rank,Questions_AnswerGroup.ColumnCou    nt,
Questions_AnswerGroup.EmailRecipient,Questions_AnswerGroup.FilterName,Questions_AnswerGroup    .ResponseName,
Questions_AnswerGroup.IsHeader,Questions_AnswerGroup.IsVariable,Questions_AnswerGroup.MaxVa    lue,
Questions_AnswerGroup.DefaultValue,Questions_AnswerGroup.CharCount,Questions_AnswerGroup.Ad    ditionalInfo,
Questions_AnswerGroup.ConditionsId,Questions_AnswerGroup.InitVisible)
SELECT Questions_AnswerGroup.QuestionId,Questions_AnswerGroup.AnswerGroupId,
Questions_AnswerGroup.ControlTypeId,Questions_AnswerGroup.IsRequired,Questions_AnswerGroup.    Rank,
Questions_AnswerGroup.ColumnCount,Questions_AnswerGroup.EmailRecipient,Questions_AnswerGrou    p.FilterName,
Questions_AnswerGroup.ResponseName,Questions_AnswerGroup.IsHeader,Questions_AnswerGroup.IsV    ariable,
Questions_AnswerGroup.MaxValue,Questions_AnswerGroup.DefaultValue,Questions_AnswerGroup.Cha    rCount,
Questions_AnswerGroup.AdditionalInfo,Questions_AnswerGroup.ConditionsId,Questions_AnswerGro    up.InitVisible
FROM Questions_AnswerGroup
inner join Questions
on Questions_AnswerGroup.QuestionId=Questions.QuestionId
where Questions.SectionId=6584
```

That gave me an output that looked like this in the Question_AnswerGroup Table:

```
QuestionAnswerGroupId   QuestionId
17438                      24990
17439                      24991
17444                      24990
17445                      24991
```

Currently both QuestionAnswerGroupIds (the orginial and the one I just duplicated) both are associated with QuestionIds that belong in Section 6584. I now need to take the two QuestionAnswerGroupIds I have created and associate them with the two questions in Section 7700 that have no answers.

```
Select questionid from Questions where sectionid=7700
```

Which Results in this:

```
questionid
31254
31255
```

So in Conculsion I need to take the two questionID's (From section 7700) above that exist in the questions table and put them in the place of the duplicates that I created above.

Edit 3: This is how the duplicate questions were created:

```
insert into Questions(Questions.Rank,Questions.QuestionText,Questions.IsActive,Sections.SectionId,Questions.ShowNumber,Questions.IsTextOnly,Questions.ContextHelp,Questions.ConditionsId,Questions.InitVisible)
select Questions.Rank,Questions.QuestionText,Questions.IsActive,(Max(Sections.SectionId)),Questions.ShowNumber,Questions.IsTextOnly,Questions.ContextHelp,Questions.ConditionsId,Questions.InitVisible
from Questions, Sections
where Questions.SectionId=6584
Group by      Questions.Rank,Questions.QuestionText,Questions.IsActive,Questions.ShowNumber,Questions.IsTextOnly,Questions.ContextHelp,Questions.ConditionsId,Questions.InitVisible
```

Comment: You are setting Y.QuestionId to x.QuestionId; however, you are using the same values to join them too, that doesn't sound right to me. Are you facing any specific issue? I mean can you give a little more details as far what the problem is?

Comment: Yes I am getting the following error: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. The result of the query in both sub queries are two records.

Comment: Please show a few rows of sample data before and after the update. It will be easier to visualize that than try to reverse engineer what we think you might have meant in your invalid query...

Comment: Still not clear what the end game is. Are you trying to change the QuestionId values in SectionId 6584 so that they have the same QuestionId values as SectionId 7700? Do you also need to update the Questions_AnswerGroup table?

Comment: So after duplicating the records in the question answer table i now have 4 answers for two questions. I previously duplicated the questions in the questions table so I now have two questions with no answers (section 7700) and 2 questions with four answers Section (6584). I was trying to replace the questionids in two of the answers with the question ids of the questions from section 7700. and yes I need to update the Questions_AnswerGroup table

Comment: Please see the updates I made to the main section fo the answer, hopefully that helps clear it up. I would appreciate any more input that can be given.

Comment: I'm still confused. You show the insert that got you the duplicate rows in Questions_AnswerGroup, but how did you get the duplicate questions (questions 31254, 31255)? I think rather than trying to figure out how to clean up the mess, you should be improving your original duplication technique. You should be able to do this in one step. What version of SQL Server is this?

Comment: Aaron, your most likely correct. I was first trying to figure out how to finish this and my other prority was to improve it all. And this is sql server 2005

Answer (score 0):

A guess but I think there are still some unanswered questions about what you're after.

```
;WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT QuestionId, r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY QuestionId)
  FROM dbo.Questions
  WHERE SectionId = 7700
), trg AS
(
  SELECT QuestionId, r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY QuestionId)
  FROM dbo.Questions
  WHERE SectionId = 6584
)
UPDATE trg
  SET QuestionId = src.QuestionId
  FROM trg INNER JOIN src
  ON trg.r = src.r;
```

Comment: Please see the updates I made to the main section fo the answer, hopefully that helps clear it up.

Comment: When I used this I replaced the trg update with the Questions_AnswerGroup table and it didnt work correctly

Comment: From looking around I though you aren't able to use ORDER BY in CTE's?

Comment: I think you are confusing using ORDER BY in a CTE and using ORDER BY within the OVER() clause.